# initializing a Map<string,string> in Typescript from json object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, initialization

I have a class in Typescript containing a map:

```
public map:Map<string,string>;
constructor() {
  let jsonString = {
    "peureo" : "dsdlsdksd"
  };
  this.map = jsonString;
}
```

Problem is that the initialization doesn't work.

`jsonString` is something that I will receive from a Java Object serialized to Json.

Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I assume because the object is serialized in a Java app. " jsonString is something that I will receive from a Java Object serialized to Json" But you're right that that's an irreverent detail.

Answer (score 7):

You must iterate over the members of the object and add it to the map:

```
public map: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();

constructor() {
    let jsonString = {
        "peureo": "dsdlsdksd"
    };

    for (let member in jsonString) {
        this.map.set(member, jsonString[member]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I originally flagged this question as a possible duplicate, but having thought about it a bit more I think there's enough differences between the plain Javascript and TypeScript that it is a standalone question ... my bad!

When the JSON is deserialized, it results in a plain object.

[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is a specific class, and you can't just cast a plain object in to a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object.

The documentation for [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) says that it's constructor takes:

> An Array or other iterable object whose elements are key-value pairs. Each key-value pair is added to the new Map; null values are treated as undefined.

Unfortunately [plain objects are not iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterables), so we can't just pass the object to [`Map's`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) constructor.

What we can do is loop over the properties, check if they're strings, and then add them to the map.

```
let objectStringPropertiesToMap = (obj: Object) => {
    let map = new Map();

    for (let key in obj) {
        let val = obj[key];

        if (typeof val == "string")
            map.set(key, val);
    }
};
```

Which would give you code something like this:

```
let obj = {
    "peureo" : "dsdlsdksd"
};

let objectStringPropertiesToMap = (obj: Object) => {
    let map = new Map();

    for (let key in obj) {
        let val = obj[key];

        if (typeof val == "string")
            map.set(key, val);
    }

    return map;
};

let map = objectStringPropertiesToMap(obj);

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = map.get("peureo");
```

Which can be seen working on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/er8Lypd3/).